# How does Photoshop's snap feature affect the image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Hey does anyone know how this feature affects the image if it is turned off? I am confused with this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bascially there is an invisible grid over your image that affects your image when you're moving layers/objects. It can also mean that layers and objects will snap to each other when you're moving them. It's useful for making pixel perfect designs (you can setup measurements in preferences) but I usually have it turned off.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Also: the grid is user configurable and can be set to visible. It will affect your document if you are trying to drag a resizing gadget and it keeps popping onto the grid, rather than the exact pixel you want. You can turn it on and off as needed for what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

If it's turned off, it won't affect your document at all. All it does is help you nail pixel-perfect placements. But more often than not, it just gets in the way. I usually have it off.

Comment: It certainly _can_ get in the way, but if you're using a grid system with guides, it's super helpful to snap to guides and grid if you configure it properly. Also, snapping to layers/document/slices is generally more helpful than not. I typically disable snap when it's getting in the way but re-enable it afterwards. It makes lining things up easier, and you can work much quicker.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.tutorial9.net/tutorials/photoshop-tutorials/tip-use-the-grid-in-photoshop/:

> Snapping is a useful feature in Photoshop that allows users to align layers, shapes, text, etc, perfectly with other objects, guides, or in our case the grid.
>
> To enable Snap to Grid, first Enable Snap (View > Snap), and then make sure Snap to Grid is checked (View > Snap To > Grid).